# Converting Python Script to Web Tool

Tags: python, django, data-visualization

I am going to make a simple website that displays data from a script I made with Beautiful Soup.  I already have a working Python code that scrapes the data I need.

What I do not know how to do is drop this Python code into a website that scrapes data on a daily basis and displays it nicely.  I am scraping daily stock prices and I want my site to store each day's price in a database and plot everything to date on a simple line graph and an accompanying table.

What keywords do I use in researching this?  I've started to look into Django vs Flask.  Am I on the right path?

Comment: You should probably separate the data scrape from the webpage. Automate the scraper to save the data to some kind of database (sql, Redis, mongoDB). And build a Flask or Django website to post a chart of some kind which pulls data from the database.

Comment: You can use any web framework to accomplish this.  Store the data in a database and separate the python code from the website code.  That way your python code can be constantly updating the DB and your data will be fresh.  Then use the web framework to query the data from the DB using SQL or similar retrieval methods.